# How can I make num_rows work for this select query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

OK, so I have this strange problem. My num_rows doesn't work, I tried everything.

So the idea, is that if there are no selected rows from the database, it should show a `<div>`. But it doesn't.

I have no error messages, so I don't know what I can do.

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT null FROM donations WHERE donateName = ? ORDER BY donateID DESC LIMIT 1", array(getUserData($this->session->userdata('logged_in')["id"], "name")));
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        if(!$query->num_rows()) { ?> 
<div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header">
                                                    <h5 class="card-header-text">I</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="card-block">
                        <ul style="margin-left: 25px; list-style: initial;">

                        <br><li>test</li>
                        </ul>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of num_rows() ?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: "CodeIgniter is based on the Model-View-Controller development pattern. MVC is a software approach that separates application logic from presentation. In practice, it permits your web pages to contain minimal scripting since the presentation is separate from the PHP scripting." [from docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html#model-view-controller). Why don't you take advantage of this approach? Why do you mix everything together in the view page?

Comment: @4Gamers : echo out the result, just above where your `if` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I've decided to edit my answer, since I was wrong.

You just need to remove your `foreach`-loop.

Comment: Ok, so I tried your version. If I try to set the $query->num_rows() == 0, it dosent return nothing. The thing that I try to do is to display a div only if there are no rows in the database.

Comment: Ok, then just remove the `foreach`-loop. Since I think it's no use.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
```

(and closing `}`).

as this would normally be to loop over the result set.  You just want to say there are no rows so just have the `if`.

You could also remove the `ORDER BY donateID` from the SQL as it doesn't really matter what order they come back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter then you may like this query format.

```
// Model
function get_count($table, $where = array(), $fields = false) {  
    // echo"<pre>";print_r($where);exit;      
    if (!$fields) {
        $fields = '*';
    }
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($where);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    // echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Call the function by providing the required arguments like

```
// Controller
$table = 'mytalbe';
$where = array(
  'id' => '34' // for example
);
$count = get_count($table, $where);
```

Hope this will help you in future to reuse the code.